# Is it possible to delete/remove an entire "select" element, after you've emptied the options with .remove()?

Tags: javascript

Like, after you've emptied it with this:

```
var select = document.GetElementById("selector");

var length = select.options.length;             
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    select.remove(select.options[i]);       
}
```

Is it possible to remove the entire node by using:

`select.parentNode.ChildNodes[1].remove();`

afterwards, keeping in mind that I have the function remove() somewhere else, as followed:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work for me. I can empty the select, but not remove it.

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in there, though. http://jsfiddle.net/jePnZ/2/

Comment: Typo.  It's `getElementById`, not `GetElementById`.

Comment: Ah yeah, stupid of me. Regardless, I don't know how to remove the select element entirely with all its' options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

if (select.parentNode.removeNode)
    select.parentNode.removeNode(select);
else
    select.parentNode.removeChild(select);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jePnZ/4/)

Comment: No, I mean, delete the entire select element. Not just an option.

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it in IE. See my updated answer, it should work now.